Uniqueness of symplectic mapping cylinder?
Given a Weinstein manifold $(X,\omega ,\phi )$ together with an exact symplectomorphism $\mu\colon X\to X$ we can form the symplectic mapping cylinder $$
M(\mu)\colon = X\times\mathbb{C}/((x,z)\sim (\mu (x), z-2\pi)).
$$There is a natural way to write down the Weinstein structure on $M(\mu)$ and we call the corresponding Weinstein manifold $M(\mu)$ a "symplectic mapping cylinder". ref. Distinguishing open symplectic tori via their wrapped Fukaya categories.
My question is, is this Weinstein structure unique? In other words, given a space $\mathfrak{X}$ together with a symplectic fibration $\mathfrak{X}\to\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ so that fibers are $X$ and monodromy around a loop exists and is symplectically isotopic to $\mu$. Does there exist a Weinstein deformation on $\mathfrak{X}$ between the given Weinstein structure and the Weinstein structure of the symplectic mapping cylinder?
